# Kotlin Destructuring when/if statement

Tags: java, string, kotlin

So I have a String i would want to check if I should split into two, or return some default value. Like this:

```
val myString = "firstPart-secondPart"
val (first, second) = when (myString.contains("-")) {
        true -> myString.split('-', limit = 2)
        else -> ?? <-- How would i return ("Default1", "Default2") so the destructuring still works?
}
```

So my question is, how do i return two default strings, so that the deconstructing works? I've used `String.split()` before in order to deconstruct and it's really nice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## How to return 2 values for destructuring

You need to return a type matching the above type, split returns a list, so you could use this:

```
listOf("Default1", "Default2")
```

## Full code

```
val myString = "firstPart-secondPart"
val (first, second) = when (myString.contains("-")) {
        true -> myString.split('-', limit = 2)
        else -> listOf("Default1", "Default2")
}
```

## Why this works

As both branches return `List<String>` you can treat the whole when block as a `List<String>`, so it can be destructured to get the values from it.

## Possible cleanup

```
val myString = "firstPart-secondPart"
val (first, second) = when {
    myString.contains("-") -> myString.split('-', limit = 2)
    else -> listOf("Default1", "Default2")
}
```

This may make more sense, assuming you are going to add more conditions, otherwise an if may make more sense.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to the good and correct answer of [jrtapsell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49256778/8073652), you could use destructured [`Pair`s](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/):

```
val (first, second) = when (myString.contains("-")) {
    true -> myString.split('-', limit = 2).let { it[0] to it[1] }
    else -> "Default1" to "Default2"
}
```

Note 1: The resulting list with two elements is transformed to a `Pair` with the help of [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html).
Note 2: The [infix function `to`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Tuples.kt) is used to create `Pair`s here.

Comment: `"Default1" to "Default2"` in this context has a bit of a code smell. I think `Pair("Default1", "Default2")`, while more verbose, is the better choice.